# Edit material UI style programatically

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make an input expand when I press the search button, but I can't change the `material-ui` style after using `makeStyles`.

Is there a way I can do it?

Thanks

Sample code:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  searchInput: {
    width: 0,
    padding: 0,
    border: "none",
  },
}));

function ExpandableSearchBar() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  function onClick() {
   // change style of the input class
   // classes.searchInput
  }

  return (
    <div className="component-wrapper">
      <IconButton onClick={onClick} aria-label="Search">
        <SearchIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <input className={classes.searchInput} type="text" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a state to toggle `className` of the input. Your code should look like -

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  searchInput: {
    width: 0,
    padding: 0,
    border: "none",
  },
  expandedSearchInput: {
    width: "5rem" // or, you can set it as per your need
    // add other styles of expanded input
  }
}));

function ExpandableSearchBar() {
  const [isExpanded,setExpand] = useState(false);
  const classes = useStyles();

  function toggleSearchInput(){
    setExpand(val => !val);
  }

  return (
    <div className="component-wrapper">
      <IconButton onClick={toggleSearchInput} aria-label="Search">
        <SearchIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <input 
        className={isExpanded ? classes.expandedSearchInput : classes.searchInput} 
        type="text" /> 
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Note -** Have a look on the `className` of the `<input/>`. It will change to `classes.expandedSearchInput` when the `isExpanded` is set to `true`.

Comment: Thanks. I think that this is a better approach ratter than change the css properties.